# Python, Putting x = 0 into a '' bracket

Tags: python, csv, selenium

Not sure if the tittle is 100% correct, please correct me if im wrong

I have a small python script as follows

```
x = 0 #counter


with open('products(x).csv', 'w') as csvfile:
```

I'm trying to make it output

`product0.csv`

I have a loop set up the increases the value of `x`

```
x += 1
```

So what I'm hoping is it will create
product0.csv
product1.csv
product2.csv

Etc, etc.

I have tried

```
with open('products'(x)'.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
```

And I just recieve an error

```
  File "web.py", line 30
    with open('products'(x)'.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
                                ^
```

Comment: What is the type of `products`? where is it defined?

Comment: products is just the first part of the name of the csv file i want to output.
its nothing related to my python code.

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
with open('products('+str(x)+').csv', 'w') as csvfile:
```

Comment: Im getting this error

  File "web.py", line 30, in <module>
    with open('product_scrapped/products('+x+').csv', 'w') as csvfile:
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Comment: @Mic updated use it

Answer (score 2):

```
with open('products({}).csv'.format(x), 'w') as csvfile:
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

String formatting should do the trick:

```
x = 0
filename = 'product{}.csv'.format(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
x = 0 #counter        
with open('products'+str(x)+'.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
```

instead of

```
x = 0 #counter        
with open('products(x).csv', 'w') as csvfile:
```

because `x` is an integer. You first need to convert it to string with `str()` and then concatenate using the `+` operator.

Another way is to use `format()` as in

```
with open('products{}.csv'.format(x), 'w')
```